# new error calc( ( 100% - 120px ) / 6 ) invalid property value chrome v47

Tags: css, google-chrome

With the latest release of Chrome v47, it appears that trying to do a `calc` value in CSS with brackets inside of brackets fails. Has anyone else noticed this?

e.g.

`calc( ( 100% - 120px ) / 6 )` is now invalid whereas in every other browser it works, and it worked in Chrome v46 too.

Comment: I didn't think you could use `calc` in that way?

Comment: Thought it would be more like this. `calc( 100% - 120px  / 6 )`

Comment: But as far as I understand the rules of mathematics state that a division or a multiplication occur in a higher priority that subtraction or addition. So that would be 120px / 6 *first*, then 100% / that value. I want to do 100% - 120px first, then / 6...

Comment: This is valid, but it only worked after removing the spaces (like this: `calc((100% - 120px) / 6 );` - that was valid in Chrome 47)

Comment: Cheers. I did try removing spaces but obviously not in the right places!

Comment: @patrickzdb After some fiddling around it appears to be that `(` and `)` don't like spaces. :)

Comment: yeah, it seems like its only the first `(` for me. I'm going to submit a bug report to chrome - it works everywhere else